# Why does Delphi 6 warn variable "i" may not have been initialized?

Tags: delphi, compiler-warnings

Optimization on/off doesn't matter.  This is simplified code to demonstrate the warning.  In the original routine all assignments and compares are to function expressions that could return a variety of values.

```
procedure test;
var i, k: integer;
begin
k := 21;
repeat
  if k = 20 then break;
  i := 5
until i = 5;
end;
```

Comment: Because if the first call of `if k = 20 then` evaluates `true` then `break` will stop the loop and there is no assignment for `i` at all. The compiler did not check the values but only the jump possibilities.

Comment: @sir:  That doesn't sound right.  The warning comes on the "until".  Put "i:=k" after the "until i=5" and the warning is still there.  "i" is definitely initialized if/when "until" is reached.  If the "break" is taken the "until" isn't reached so "i" shouldn't matter.  Still seems like an inappropriate warning.

Comment: Thats why the warning tells you *"... **may not** have been initialized"*. There is no deep analysis of your code

Comment: "Deep" analysis isn't necessary.  The warning simply shouldn't appear on any line immediately preceded by an assignment to the variable in question, which is the case here.  If the warning came on the "end", the warning would be true, but still worthless since there are no references to "i" there.  The compiler seems to be fooled by the "break", as though the break leads to the "until" like a "continue" would.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does seem to be a weakness in the compiler.

```
repeat
  if k = 20 then break;
  i := 5
until i = 5;
```

A human static analysis can easily check that `i` is always assigned before it is read. The line before the `until` assigns it. If that assignment is skipped by the `break`, then the `until` test is also skipped.

So, this can only be described as a compiler bug because the compiler should be able to understand how `break` and `until` interact. Clearly the compiler's analysis depends on an understanding of these things, since removing the `break` will also remove the warning. So it can only be that the compiler doesn't understand well enough.

It turns out that the 32 bit Windows compiler still behaves the same way in the current Delphi release, XE7. But the 64 bit compiler correctly emits no warning for your code.

Note that you might expect the compiler to realise that the condition in the `if` test in your code always evaluates `False`. Well, the compiler won't. It does not perform static analysis of constant propagation through non constant variables. Its analysis takes no account of the values that you place in variables.

Comment: The compiler does perform data-flow analysis. For example, it performs live-variable analysis (to hint when a variable is assigned but not used) and definite-assignment analysis (to warn when a variable is used before it's assigned). The code in question shows the latter is buggy. What Delphi doesn't do is perform constant propagation through non-const variables, so the expression `k = 20` isn't evaluated at compile time, even though a sufficiently smart compiler could know the value of `k`.

Comment: Thank you @Rob, my use of terminology was very sloppy

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Delphi warns you about this is the fact that local variables don't get initialized automatically. What this means? This means that if you try reading any such variable it will return some more or less random result (contents of the memory it points to).

So as soon as Delphi recognizes a posibility that some variable might be read before anything is written to it (initialization of a variable does write a default value into it) the warning will be raised.
And this would happen in your code if the value of "k" would be 20 becouse the "i := 5" line would be skipped.

How do you solve this warning in your case? Simply set some value to "i" outside any loops or any conditional statments. For instance:

```
procedure test;
var i, k: integer;
begin
  //Set initial value for i
  i := 0;
  k := 21;
  repeat
    if k = 20 then break;
    i := 5
  until i = 5;
end;
```

Comment: The asker knows all of this but wants to know whether or not the warning is a false positive and suspects that the compiler should not warn in this instance.

Comment: The fact is that compiler can't know if this is false positive not unless testing all posible scenarios. But that is the job for a programmer.

Comment: The compiler can know that.

Comment: How could compiler know that wthout compiling the actual code and testing all posible scenarios?

Comment: The test in the until only executes if the loop body runs to completion. And if it does, the variable is assigned. What scenario do you have in mind where the test is performed and the variable has not been assigned?

Comment: I realy doubt that compiler treats "until" part of repeat loop as last line of inner code block. So when it detects that part of inner code might not get executed it doesen also treats that "until" part of repeat loop also won't be executed.

Comment: If it did that, and knows that the `break` will lead to the `until` test being skipped, then why is it warning about the test in the until accessing an uninitialized variables? And why is the 64 bit compiler able to handle this correctly?

Comment: I suspect that what you are missing is the fact that the warning is only triggered when you attempt to read a variable. If the compiler knows that you never read it, it won't warn that you failed to assign it. You may get an unused local var *hint* but that's different.

Comment: I think the only way an "until" can be reached is by "continue" or from the immediately preceding statement or by a "goto" a label on the "until".  Since there is no goto or continue, and since "i" is assigned prior to the "until", there should be no warning.  I'm guessing the compiler warning logic is wrongly treating the "break" like "continue".

Comment: @WitnessProtectionID44583292  A `continue` starts the next iteration. Not `until` test, it is straight back to the first line after `repeat`.

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  I see continue jump to until.

Comment: @WitnessProtectionID44583292 is right. Continue does jump to until. If it would not and jump straight to the first line in block as you sad using if Continue would break the repeat loop boudaries and thus could even reesult in an endless loop.

Comment: The documentation is confusing then. The fact that an endless loop can be made is neither here nor there. Many things can make endless loops.

Comment: The documentation says *You can use the standard Break and Continue procedures to control the flow of a repeat, while, or for statement. Break terminates the statement in which it occurs, while Continue begins executing the next iteration of the sequence.* I took that mean mean that a continue in a repeat loop moves execution to the first statement after repeat. Clearly that's not what happens. Thank you both for teaching me that fact.

Comment: I can understand why you thought like so. The reapeat loop is the only one which checks for the exit condition on the end of its loop while both for loop and while loop check the end condition before starting their cycle.